# How does a link that requires authentication work?

Tags: javascript, authentication, url

Suppose I sign in to Facebook and I'm looking at a private event. I want to send that link to my friend so that he can join the event. However, doing so requires my friend to log in to Facebook (to be authenticated), so that he can view the event and join it. In other words:

1. I'm logged in, and am on the event page. I copy the URL.
2. I paste it to my friend and he clicks on it.
3. The page isn't accessible to her until she signs in
4. After signing in, it redirects back to the event page.

My question lies in going from step 3 to 4. How is the original link to the event page "remembered"? Is that event-page link stored somewhere, then applied after a login? It's unclear me how the page knows to be redirected after a user logs in when the physical URL has already changed to the login page.

Note: I don't know if this is how it actually works with Facebook. This was just an example. My question doesn't revolve around how to invite people to Facebook events.

Comment: There is logic on the server-side that is checking if a user is logged in. It's not in the URL itself.

Comment: The request for page.html hits the server, it identifies the user is not logged in and either redirects to the login page passing a `&jumpto=page.html` argument thats read and redirected to on a successful login, or it stores the page url in the session and does the same.

Answer (score 2):

Redirect from the security url to login with params like `http://somehost/login?from=enteredURL` (where the GET param  `from` holds the route he tried to access before he got redirected) and redirect to "entered/from" URL after a successfull login -> **done**. Simple at it is but it works fine!

In JavaScript your direct what look like this:

```
window.location = window.location.origin + 
                    '/login?from=' +  
                     encodeURI((location.pathname+location.search).substr(1))
```

This result in e.g.:

> http://www.test.com/login?from=/user/profile/me

Comment: Originally, when I view the link on my browser, I don't see a `from=enteredURL`. Is that added after I copy and paste?

Comment: No, your have to inject it in your redirect URL.

Comment: but what if I copy from the URL bar?

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand you.

Comment: Will that still be injected if from the URL bar?

Comment: Still dont understand you, sorry. You have to implement the logic inside your application.

Answer (score 0):

The original location (the event page URL) is included as extra data in the login URL.

When your friend goes to the event page without being logged in, Facebook sends back a response that redirects her browser to `/login?original=/event-page`. The extra data after the `?` is called the query string. When she logs in, Facebook receives the query string data and sends back a response that redirects her browser to the event page.

So the original destination is just preserved in the URL.